# How do I log out of my stack exchange account?

Tags: support, login

I want to create a new profile, so how do I log out of BSE?

Answer (score 4):

Before I answer, I should let you know that creating another account to circumvent a ban is *really* not a good idea. It will get you in more trouble then just writing lousy questions (and the account will be deleted.)

However I suspect you will anyway (you haven't seemed to listen to the advice anyone has given you so far) so: [How to log out of a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222556/278094)
[image]

Comment: Who could guess that you actually have 932k rep on BSE..

Comment: you got to have some fun with these screen shots. :) PS that is not the only fun change.

Comment: Is it a bug????